# Regex match at least two or one word

Tags: regex

I'd like to create regex to find at least two words or one

For ex

I have this phrases

```
I will buy a car
I will buy a horse
I will buy an electronic device
I will buy chip electronic
a device electronic will buy by my uncle
```

And I'm using
`(buy|eletronic)(?:\W+\w+){1,7}?\W+(buy|eletronic)`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/g1IUXm/1

I'd like to find

```
I will buy an electronic device
I will buy chip electronic
a device electronic will buy by my uncle
```

and if I used just **buy** I'd like to find all phrases

Comment: You should state your question in words and then present your example, showing the desired result. Only then present your regex and state why it is incorrect. I think you wish to select all lines containing the words "buy" and "electronic", in any order, separated by at 1-7 characters. Is that correct? Note that `\W+\w+` matches line terminators, "eletronic" in `(buy|eletronic)` is misspelled (both instances) and `"buy seven buy"`. satisfies your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first pattern, you can use a backreference if that is supported with a negative lookahead (note that there is also a typo in your pattern `eletronic` missing a `c` char)

For the example I have omitted matching a newline for `\W`

```
\b(buy|electronic)(?:[^\w\n]+\w+){1,7}?[^\w\n]+(?!\1)(?:buy|electronic)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2k1ra/1)

If you want to match all lines with the word `buy`:

```
.*\bbuy\b.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex if you want to match the whole line that contains `buy` or `eletronic` before `buy` or `eletronic`.

```
^.*?(?:buy|eletronic).*?(?:buy|electronic).*?$
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/FXtByF/1

Answer (score 0):

The way to use 'contains' in regex is to use look aheads.

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*buy)(?=.*electronic).*
```

Use `global` and `multiline` flags.

**Explanation**:

`^` - match from start of line

`(?=.*buy)` - look ahead for any character zero or more times followed by `buy`

`(?=.*electronic)` - look ahead for any character zero or more times followed by `electronic`

`.*` - match rest of line

If you only want one word match, you can simply drop the other.

If you want to catch the words you can surround them with parentheses to create groups.